# Why is absolute child of a sticky is always hiding behind another sticky?

Tags: css

I am trying to have a sticky first column as well as some CSS tooltips. Here is a simplified model of my setup:

```css
div.container
{
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td 
{
  border: 1px black solid;
}


td div 
{
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
}

td:first-child
{
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lime;
}


[data-tooltip]:hover:after
{
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  top: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div data-tooltip="123">hover me</div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
    <tr>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that the tooltip hides behind the cell on the next row and I can't find any solution for that (other than removing `position: sticky`) which is not an acceptable solution in my case.

What should I do to bring the tooltip in front? `z-index` seems to do nothing in this case.

Answer (score 8):

You need to increase the `z-index` of only the first sticky element. Both have the same `z-index` so we will consider the tree order to paint them and both create a stacking context so adjusting the `z-index` of the `position:absolute` element will have no effect:

```css
div.container
{
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td 
{
  border: 1px black solid;
}


td div 
{
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
}

td:first-child
{
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lime;
}
tr:first-child  td:first-child{
  z-index:2;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover:after
{
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  top: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><div data-tooltip="123">hover me</div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      <td><div></div>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

For more details about the painting order: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html

Comment: This only works for the first column in the first row. If table had more rows, you'd have to create a hierarchy of z-indices for each successive row. There has to be some sort of solution to this or is this a `position:sticky` bug?

Comment: @wlh it's not a bug, it's the logical paiting order ... we paint later element after since both have the same z-index. It will not only happen with sticky, and in case will have many rows then we can probably think about a complete new way to do this

Comment: @wlh by the way, no need any hierarchy of z-indices, we only need to make the needed element with a higher z-index and it will be above all the others

Comment: Lets say you had twenty rows, (let's not even get started with dynamically created rows), the z-index of the first row, first cell would need to be 20, then second row, 19, third row 18, etc etc etc. Every successive row that would potentially have a tooltip would need to have its z-index defined one lower than the previous row.

Comment: You would have to do something like this (example of four rows): https://jsfiddle.net/vu7jy14b/

Comment: @wlh if we really have something like this then we should re-think the code ... a simple fix would be to consider the popup on the top and not the bottom. In all the cases the most important part is to understand what's happening (the purpose of my answer) then we should find a *clever* way for each situation.

Comment: Why doesn't the same happen without sticky? I mean remove `position: sticky`, add `[data-tooltip] { position: relative; }` so absolute tooltip has the correct parent and the tooltips are on top of any cell. Why doesn't the painting order interfere with that?

Comment: @Džuris because position:relative doesn't create a stacking context like sticky (as I said in my anwser) use `position:relative` + `z-index:0` and you will have the same behavior ... when you have a stacking context the element should be place inside this context

Comment: @Džuris by the way, can you show me how it's not the same with relative? because in this particular case, even if both aren't the same visually you will have the same result

Comment: @TemaniAfif I meant [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8en493k1/) - static position for the cells, relative position for div and it works. That's how I did it before I had to make the first column sticky.

Comment: @Džuris it's because the cell are static now and we paint the postionned element after the static ones, so all of them will be painted above the green which belong to static element but the tootip are painted considering the tree order but since they are far you won't see any issue

Answer (score 0):

This is probem with "position:sticky" when you loop for many row using sticky, the combox can't show full. The solution is let the first row have higest z-index, then minus 1 for each row like this, your combobox can be show. Sorry I'm using LWC framework in Salesforce so it can be a litte different but the logic is good as well.

```js
z_index = 4000;

get getRowStyle() {
    this.z_index--;
    return `z-index: ${this.z_index} !important;`;
}
```

```html
<thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class:"col 1"></td>
            <td class:"col 2" style={getRowStyle}>your dropdown in here</td>
            <td class:"col 3"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```